# AWS CodePipeline role is not authorized to perform AssumeRole on Role in "action" block of a stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, cicd

The "Deploy" stage in my CodePipeline should be having a different IAM Role (*Arn*: `another_codepipeline_role_arn`) than that of the CodePipeline (*Arn*: `codepipeline_role_arn`). Below is my terraform configuration.

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {
    name     = "test_pipeline"
    role_arn = var.codepipeline_role_arn

    artifact_store {
        location = aws_s3_bucket.codepipeline_bucket.bucket
        type     = "S3"
    }
    ...
    stage {
        name = "Deploy"
        action {
            name            = "Deploy"
            category        = "Deploy"
            owner           = "AWS"
            provider        = "CloudFormation"
            input_artifacts = ["build_output"]
            version         = "1"

            configuration = {
                ActionMode     = "CREATE_UPDATE"
                Capabilities   = "CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND,CAPABILITY_IAM"
                OutputFileName = var.codepipeline_output_filename
                StackName      = "test-stack"
                TemplatePath   = "build_output::packaged.yaml"
            }
            role_arn = var.another_codepipeline_role_arn
        }
    }
}
```

However on applying the changes, Terraform throws out this error:

```
Error: Error creating CodePipeline: InvalidStructureException: arn:aws:iam::account_id:role/codepipeline_role is not authorized to perform AssumeRole on role arn:aws:iam::account_id:role/another_codepipeline_role
```

It may also be noted that I have already specified `codepipeline.amazonaws.com` in the `Service` section of the `AssumeRole` policy document (sample below):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "codepipeline.amazonaws.com"
                  ]
                },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

PS: Attaching the roles `codepipeline_role_arn` and `another_codepipeline_role_arn` below:

**codepipeline_role_arn:**

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": [
                        "cloudformation.amazonaws.com",
                        "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com",
                        "ec2.amazonaws.com",
                        "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:CancelUploadArchive",
                "codecommit:GetBranch",
                "codecommit:GetCommit",
                "codecommit:GetRepository",
                "codecommit:GetUploadArchiveStatus",
                "codecommit:UploadArchive",
                "codepipeline:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "codedeploy:CreateDeployment",
                "codedeploy:GetApplication",
                "codedeploy:GetApplicationRevision",
                "codedeploy:GetDeployment",
                "codedeploy:GetDeploymentConfig",
                "codedeploy:RegisterApplicationRevision"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "codestar-connections:UseConnection"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:*",
                "ec2:*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:*",
                "autoscaling:*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "s3:*",
                "sns:*",
                "cloudformation:*",
                "rds:*",
                "sqs:*",
                "ecs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:ListFunctions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "opsworks:CreateDeployment",
                "opsworks:DescribeApps",
                "opsworks:DescribeCommands",
                "opsworks:DescribeDeployments",
                "opsworks:DescribeInstances",
                "opsworks:DescribeStacks",
                "opsworks:UpdateApp",
                "opsworks:UpdateStack"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DeleteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:SetStackPolicy",
                "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "codebuild:BatchGetBuilds",
                "codebuild:StartBuild",
                "codebuild:BatchGetBuildBatches",
                "codebuild:StartBuildBatch"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "devicefarm:ListProjects",
                "devicefarm:ListDevicePools",
                "devicefarm:GetRun",
                "devicefarm:GetUpload",
                "devicefarm:CreateUpload",
                "devicefarm:ScheduleRun"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "servicecatalog:ListProvisioningArtifacts",
                "servicecatalog:CreateProvisioningArtifact",
                "servicecatalog:DescribeProvisioningArtifact",
                "servicecatalog:DeleteProvisioningArtifact",
                "servicecatalog:UpdateProduct"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:DescribeImages"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "states:DescribeExecution",
                "states:DescribeStateMachine",
                "states:StartExecution"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "appconfig:StartDeployment",
                "appconfig:StopDeployment",
                "appconfig:GetDeployment"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

**another_codepipeline_role_arn:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:Describe*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "logs:*",
                "sns:*",
                "iam:GetPolicy",
                "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
                "iam:GetRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": "events.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*",
                "dax:*",
                "application-autoscaling:DeleteScalingPolicy",
                "application-autoscaling:DeregisterScalableTarget",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalableTargets",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingPolicies",
                "application-autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
                "application-autoscaling:RegisterScalableTarget",
                "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmHistory",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmsForMetric",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricData",
                "datapipeline:ActivatePipeline",
                "datapipeline:CreatePipeline",
                "datapipeline:DeletePipeline",
                "datapipeline:DescribeObjects",
                "datapipeline:DescribePipelines",
                "datapipeline:GetPipelineDefinition",
                "datapipeline:ListPipelines",
                "datapipeline:PutPipelineDefinition",
                "datapipeline:QueryObjects",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:ListAliases",
                "sns:CreateTopic",
                "sns:DeleteTopic",
                "sns:ListSubscriptions",
                "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                "sns:ListTopics",
                "sns:Subscribe",
                "sns:Unsubscribe",
                "sns:SetTopicAttributes",
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "lambda:ListEventSourceMappings",
                "lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:DeleteEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:DeleteFunction",
                "resource-groups:ListGroups",
                "resource-groups:ListGroupResources",
                "resource-groups:GetGroup",
                "resource-groups:GetGroupQuery",
                "resource-groups:DeleteGroup",
                "resource-groups:CreateGroup",
                "tag:GetResources",
                "kinesis:ListStreams",
                "kinesis:DescribeStream",
                "kinesis:DescribeStreamSummary"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": "cloudwatch:GetInsightRuleReport",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": [
                        "application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com",
                        "application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com.cn",
                        "dax.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": [
                        "replication.dynamodb.amazonaws.com",
                        "dax.amazonaws.com",
                        "dynamodb.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com",
                        "contributorinsights.dynamodb.amazonaws.com",
                        "kinesisreplication.dynamodb.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "apigateway:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-identity:*",
                "cognito-idp:*",
                "cognito-sync:*",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:ListOpenIdConnectProviders",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:ListSAMLProviders",
                "iam:GetSAMLProvider",
                "kinesis:ListStreams",
                "lambda:GetPolicy",
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "sns:GetSMSSandboxAccountStatus",
                "sns:ListPlatformApplications",
                "ses:ListIdentities",
                "ses:GetIdentityVerificationAttributes",
                "mobiletargeting:GetApps",
                "acm:ListCertificates"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": [
                        "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com",
                        "email.cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeleteServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:GetServiceLinkedRoleDeletionStatus"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "states:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:ListStackResources",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricData",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "kms:ListAliases",
                "iam:GetPolicy",
                "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "lambda:*",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "states:DescribeStateMachine",
                "states:ListStateMachines",
                "tag:GetResources",
                "xray:GetTraceSummaries",
                "xray:BatchGetTraces"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:GetLogEvents",
                "logs:FilterLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/lambda/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the role and permissions that you use for `codepipeline_role_arn`?

Comment: Pretty much full access permissions for various services

Comment: Which is what exactly?

Comment: @Marcin, I've updated the permissions in the question

Comment: I also noticed that all your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances for your questions to be actually answered.

Comment: @Marcin, thank you

Comment: For anyone else who gets puzzled by resolving this issue and then getting hit with a `Pipeline not created yet` error - you need to call `pipeline.buildPipeline()` before referencing it (such as in your Role's `assumedBy` field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your `codepipeline_role_arn` nor `another_codepipeline_role_arn` allows for `sts:AssumeRole` action for your pipelines. Which off course results in your error that `AssumeRole` is not permitted.

You have to modify your `codepipeline_role` and **add** `sts:AssumeRole` permissions to it, so that pipeline can assume the roles you want.